# Splitting a string and assigning to different variables

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have got the date range from the ui as - approved_between"=>"2013-03-17 - 2013-03-18"

I need to split this approved_start_date="2013-03-17" and approved_end_date="2013-03-18"....I am hoping to use this to query in mysql as the date format in mysql is created_at: 2012-07-28 10:35:01.

What I'm doing is-:

```
approved = approved_between.split(" ")
approved_start_date = approved[0]
approved_end_date = approved[2]
```

Pretty sure this isn't the most optimum way to process it, any better suggestions out there like split string in a single line, and assign them directly to variable?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

that should be

```
approved_start_date, approved_end_date = approved_between.split(" - ")
```

UPDATE:  using the dates in mysql

```
MyModel.where('DATE(created_at) = ?', approved_start_date)
```

Comment: Beauty :) Btw Will I able to query using this in MySQL? Can MySQL compare the approved_start_date, with data in created_at column?

Comment: nope. `created_at` column is of type datetime so you have to get the date part of `created_at` first like in my updated answer.

Comment: Excellent...Thanks for replying back so fasat